# How to say if an element belongs to a specific b-Tree in Prolog?

Tags: data-structures, prolog

I have the following program that represent a specific b-tree by the `t` predicate and provides the `in/2` predicate that says if an element `X` belongs to this tree:

```
t(
   t(nil, b, nil),      
   a,               
   t(t(nil,d,nil), c, nil)  
).

in(X, t(_,X,_)).        
in(X, t(L,_,_)) :- in(X,L).     
in(X, t(_,_,R)) :- in(X,R).
```

My problem is that I don't know how to execute this query in the Prolog shell using these two predicates.

For example, what do I have to do to ask Prolog if the `d` element is in the represented tree (obtaining *true*) or if the element `z` is in this tree (obtaining *false*)?

Comment: You've been asked at least once a day for the last two weeks to spell check your questions. SPELL CHECK YOUR QUESTIONS.

Comment: You are right...I will try to do it, I promise :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the problem is that `t/3` doesn't belong in your fact database, it belongs in the query. Or perhaps that `t/3` isn't a predicate at all, but merely a fact (though the distinction is less meaningful than it seems at first blush). But we can work with this, we just need to do some reconstruction:

```
?- t(A,B,C), T=t(A,B,C), in(d,T).
A = t(nil, b, nil),
B = a,
C = t(t(nil, d, nil), c, nil),
T = t(t(nil, b, nil), a, t(t(nil, d, nil), c, nil))

?- t(A,B,C), T=t(A,B,C), in(z,T).
false.
```

The `T=t(A,B,C)` gymnastic is necessary to rebuild your tree. It would be more clear if you had predicates for creating trees, so you could make a query that looks more like this:

```
?- empty_tree(T), 
   insert(T, a, T1), 
   insert(T1, b, T2), 
   insert(T2, c, T3), 
   in(c, T3).
```

Or you could store your tree like this:

```
tree(t(t(nil,b,nil),a,t(t(nil,d,nil),c,nil)).
```

And then your query would look more like:

```
?- tree(T), in(d, T).
```

Comment: Ok, now it is pretty clear. I apologize for my mistakes in English language. I am try to study quickly and often I forget to check the spell...